# PHP Ajax right structure

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, structure

I found a similar questions, but it's not exactly what I am looking for.

I write web site using php. For dynamic content I use jQuery Ajax.

I have 20-50 functions and I want to use Ajax to call these functions and take JSON.
 Idea is to pass parametres via ajax POST. Pages works with database and job is done.

**The question - how better organize it?**

Should I create 50 separate pages like:

```
mysite.com/ajax/delete_project.php
mysite.com/ajax/delete_user.php
mysite.com/ajax/show_user_info.php
mysite.com/ajax/show_my_messages.php
mysite.com/ajax/show_my_tasks.php
mysite.com/ajax/send_message.php
```

.......

or create one page? or maybe i am completely wrong with all of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should be using a framework, such as Symfony. Otherwise, I usually keep all the functions for each content type in a single file. So you might have:

mysite.com/api/blog_posts.php which would implement GET, POST, PUT, DEL, etc... for all the blog posts.  Meanwhile, mysite.com/api/messages.php would handle that for all messages.

Answer (score 0):

You must start using an MVC framework if not using already. I would say Laravel should be a good choice, it's easy to learn, feature-rich and fun to work with. Start looking into Laravel Routes.

Moving to MVC is the best way to start getting into shape in your case.